# Why does unity keep my Canvas deactivated with OnTriggerEnter()? Acitvate Text with Collider in Untiy2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, text, topdown

I can't activate my Canvas with my Interactable(Coin) Script and the OnTriggerEnter(). I want to activate the Canvas(show my Text) when my Player collides with my Coin. The Script is in my Coin GameObject. My CoinCollider is on IsTrigger.

```
public string displayText;
public Text textView;
public GameObject Player;
public Canvas textCanvas;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    textCanvas.enabled = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

void onTriggerEnter(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        textCanvas.enabled = true;
        textView.text = displayText;

    }
}
```

I tried making just the Text appear without a Canvas and watching Tutorials.

Comment: Do your colliding GameObjects have colliders attached to them? And are you in 2D space since you use Collider2D?

Comment: Yeah it's a 2D TopDown Game and both GameObjects have a Collider.

Comment: I'm not able to test it right now, but you should also use `other.compareTag("Player");` since it has fewer CIL instruction. Also check if your tag is written correctly and try `Debug.Log(other.tag);` so you can see if and with what your coin collides.

Comment: The compareTag() was not the problem it's never going in the onTriggerEnter() function that's the problem, Debug.Log(other.tag); gets never displayed, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the method name is "OnTriggerEnter2D" not "onTriggerEnter" for 2D collisions. This sho

Comment: Yeah thanks so much, I'm so Braindead i should make a break now.

Comment: No worries, Unity is very bad with its MonoBehavior functions, I struggled a lot with it XS